# Modify nodes in compositing nodetree using Python

Tags: python, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I want to setup basic node tree using Python operator and I cannot use compositor context. Hint over node values pointed to this data path:

```
bpy.data.node_groups["Compositing Nodetree"].nodes["Alpha Over"].premul
```

but this collection: `bpy.data.node_groups` includes only custom node groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T35720 pointed me to the right data path. When you want to modify the node tree in compositor, then you have to use the following path:

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes['Alpha Over'].premul
```

or you can use the following syntax to avoid the hard-coded name of the scene (the current scene will be used):

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['Alpha Over'].premul
```

and it just works. :-)

Comment: You can also use `bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes` to avoid hardcoding the name for the scene.

Comment: @pycoder you are right. Thanks for reminder. I will update answer.